# If the product of spaces is normal, then factor are normal.

Tags: general-topology, infinite-product

I am proving that if the product space $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is normal, then any $X_\alpha$ is normal.

So far I have this:

Let $A$ be closed in $X_\alpha$, then $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(A)$ is a closed set of $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$. Given some neighborhood $U$ of $A$, then $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(U)$ is an open set that contains $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(A)$. Since the product space is normal, there exists some open set $V\subset \pi_\alpha^{-1}(U)$ s.t. $\pi^{-1}_\alpha(A)\subset V$ and $\overline{V} \subset \pi_\alpha^{-1}(U)$. Then $\pi_\alpha (V)$ is an open set (since $\pi_\alpha$ is an open map), $A\subset \pi_\alpha(V) \subset U$ and $\overline{\pi_\alpha(V)} \subset \pi_\alpha(\overline{V}) \subset U$.

Is my thought correct? Any comments?

Comment: in the title the first occurrence of "normal" does not belong there

Comment: Typos: s.t. $\pi^{-1}_\alpha(A) \subset V$ and ... /  Then $\pi_\alpha(V)$ is ....

Comment: Why $\overline{\pi_\alpha(V)} \subset \pi_\alpha(\overline{V})$?

Comment: @PaulFrost I think that the property of closures follows from the projections being open.

Comment: @PaulFrost Anyway, I think the contention of closures $\overline{\pi_\alpha(V)} \subset U$ is true, perhaps it is easier to prove it directly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose some factor is not normal. Choose two disjoint closed sets that cannot be separated by open sets.

Then consider closed sets in the product that use these closed sets at the relevant factor, and the whole space for each other factor. These also cannot be separated by open sets, proving the product is not normal.

Comment: @NestorBravo See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers